# Firebase messaging works only in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    }];


    [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    [FIRApp configure];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];


    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {


   [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
   NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {


}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {


    [self connectToFcm];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

}




- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {



    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"message 1");
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {


    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"message 2");
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}



- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"message 3");
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }


    NSLog(@"full data : %@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);


}



- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"message 1");
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"applicationReceivedRemoteMessage  : %@", remoteMessage.appData);

}


- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    if(!(refreshedToken== nil)){
        [defaults setValue:refreshedToken forKey:@"FcmToken"];
    }


    [self connectToFcm];


}

- (void)connectToFcm {

    if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
        return;
    }


    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken); 
}

enter code here
```

When app is in the background mode, message not coming. When app is running foreground mode message shows in applicationReceivedRemoteMessage function. I need to run some code when message comes when background mode. Can anyone give me the solution for get the notifications works in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

> FIRMessaging connection won’t be allowed to live when in background it
>   is prudent to close the connection.

Please find here reference for the same: [disconnect()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(im)disconnect)

[FirebaseMessaging Framework Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging)

Simple Logic About Chat Applications: **Socket Connection**

Generally, Chat applications connects with other nodes (devices) using socket connection to transmit real-time information between nodes. **Socket connections are disconnected, when apps goes into background.**

FirebaseMessaging works on same logic and hence is won't work in background.

To handle message transmission in background mode, use power of **PushNotification**.

Also mark your code: You are disconnecting FIRMessaging when application goes into background. And you've done this, because the same is instructed in FIRMessaging guidelines.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

   [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
   NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
```

*As an alternate solution of your problem: You may have analyzed Whatapp or Facebook Messagner app. They use push notification to alert user for messages, when app goes into background. You should do the same.*

Comment: so what you suggest as solution??

Comment: You may have analyzed Whatapp or Facebook Messagner app. They use push notification to alert user for messages, when app goes into background

Comment: here my problem is when in background, i am not getting the alert either to the app.

Comment: Alert mean FIRMessage or Push Notification?

Comment: Push notification i mean.

Comment: Is it(Push Notification) working in fore-ground mode. I mean does it print any value for `NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);` inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification`